Where do I start from when tiling a concrete slab porch with one step?
Below is the porch. It was properly sloped and I want to make sure I maintain that slope while tiling
These are 20mmx24"x36" tiles.
If I use a long level that sits with one end at the steps side and the other end at the door side of the porch I can see a slope there and there are areas where I have some gaps at max 1/4". These are tiles designed to support pedestrians when sitting on pedestals so I am not worried if there might be gaps in coverage. I will mark with chalk the areas where I have gaps and add more thinset there
Having these said I am tempted to start from the stairs end because I have coping tiles and I want to make sure that side looks good (it is the first thing that caches the eye and I want the things properly aligned there. Besides that I do not want to have to narrow down the coping tile, I need it to be the same size as the one sitting on the first step.
There I have an issue with a 1/2" max gap between raiser tile cuts and the concrete slab, see the second picture.
So I have lots of reasons to start at the stairs end but then I need to somehow make sure I maintain the slope of the slab,.
What is the best way to do this ?
PS: the precast concrete step you see there has the nose shaved already




With the tile laying up towards the door, and the painted wood that the tile will eventually meet, is the painted wood that goes to the original surface removable? That way, you can cut it down and reset or replace it after the tile is set and it won't be trapped between 2 moisture holding items, brick and tile. If it is and older home, it may be a 3" thick sill that goes well back in the opening, then that is not advisable to remove. If you have a large overhang on the roof, that may protect it well enough.

the door sits on something that covered in aluminum fushing and at the bottom it has aluminum sill (I think that is the term) That threshold is elevated and there is caulking at the contact zone between concrete and flushing ...the plan is to leave around 1/2" expansion gap on the perimeter of the porch. That should allow me to later remove the grout on the door side and replace it or work from the inside to do it. The door needs to be replaced sooner or later
Yes 60Y old house, the porch has a roof above it

You can start at the steps and work toward the door.  That will be a little inconvenient, but it can get you the result you want.
You may want to cover the floor inside the doors and be sure they are able to be opened all the way for when your get there.
It you are using leveling clips the slope should be preserved.

Yes using leveling clips but they look fragile for these tiles.I could not find1/8 for 20mm tiles so I had to buy 1/16 and plan to use my own spacers from above. The doors ooen toward inside and they are sitting way above the porch level like 1.5" or higher
