How can I protect ungrouted tile over the winter?
Due to supplier delays and some personal matters I have finished installing 20mm outdoor tiles on my 6'x8' porch recently (late November) but due to lower temps I don't think I will be able to install the grout too soon.(Mapei Ultracolor Plus FA). I will be watching the forecast for temps above 10C but not sure if I would be seeing that soon here in Toronto.
What should I do to protect the tiles from getting water under them and from being affected by water freezing there?

How far above the grade is this porch?

See this https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/309105/where-do-i-start-from-when-tiling-a-concrete-slab-porch-with-one-step?noredirect=1#comment656647_309105

you think grout will keep moisture out?

I would enclose the porch in plastic and use a heater to get the temp. above the 10C needed to grout.
Do the grouting and keep the temperature constant for 24 hrs. Remove the heater, but leave the plastic up for another 24 hrs.  Giving the grout time to cure before being exposed to extreme low temperatures.

that is in theory a good solution. However enclosing the porch is not feasible. I have a bricks facade and  exterior walls -the old English style and that implies mortar gaps between bricks. Trying to air tight those gaps will be a herculean task.

You don't need to be "air tight"  Just warm enough to grout.

Then line the walls with plastic sheet as well, like making a tent... @MiniMe Just need to be creative or apply common sense to the problem. Or just make a "tent" over the porch area.

Or maybe use heat blankets?  Heat up the tile and substrate, apply grout, cover with blanket til it's cured.  Work areas only as big as you have blanket for?  Or simply cover it all in plastic sheet, lay some plywood on top to walk on, and do the job in the spring.

Considering some polyurethane like I used here 10y ago https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52169/how-do-i-seal-a-gap-between-a-concrete-step-and-the-entrance-of-the-house  that to get me over winter

@MiniMe,  are you saying you would use polyurethane caulk instead of grout?...and then dig it all out in the spring!

yes that would be the plan
the tiles are 20mm so there is a challenge to push the grout all the way down in each 1/8" grout line
the sides (the edge next to the walls) are 1/2"

The poly stays flexible and that is lousy to have as a grout base, and digging it out is something I would never want to do. ( Far more work than putting up plastic to make a heat tent)  but it's your project.

Don't put poly caulk between tiles if you can help it. It will be very difficult to clean the tiles properly later, and clean they will need to be for the grout to adhere properly. Rigid grouts make the surface structurally monolithic and impermeable, and are the Only True Thing to put between tiles, in my admittedly dogmatic opinion.

What if I put a backer rod before adding a thin layer of caulk?
